# Magento addImageToMediaGallery moves images regardless of arg

Tags: magento

Function def:

```
void addImageToMediaGallery (string $file, [string|array $mediaAttribute = null], [boolean $move = false], [boolean $exclude = true])
```

I'm calling it like:

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($fileName, '', false, false);
```

Even though the $move arg is set to false,  magento is still moving my image file to "media/catalog/product/f/i/filename.jpg",  instead of using the original file location of the image, which is "media/catalog/product/12/1234/o.1234.jpg".

In my code, $fileName is set to "media/catalog/product/12/1234/o.1234.jpg".

Am I missing something here?